# How to change the color of the title in TTLauncherItem?

Tags: three20, ttlauncherview, ttlauncheritem

I am having a lot of trouble trying to change the color in the TTLauncherItem, because the default gray color does no work with my background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I used to change the text color of `TTLauncherItem` from the default gray color to black (looks better on a white background):

(1) Create a Stylesheet that inherits from `TTDefaultStyleSheet`:

Stylesheet.h:

```
@interface StyleSheet : TTDefaultStyleSheet {}   
@end
```

Stylesheet.m:

```
// Style for TTLauncherItems
- (TTStyle*)launcherButton:(UIControlState)state {
    return 
    [TTPartStyle styleWithName: @"image" 
                         style: TTSTYLESTATE(launcherButtonImage:, state) 
                          next: [TTTextStyle 
                                 styleWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11]
                                 color: RGBCOLOR(0, 0, 0)
                                 minimumFontSize: 11 
                                 shadowColor: nil
                                 shadowOffset: CGSizeZero 
                                 next: nil]];
}
```

(2) In AppDelegate.m, initialize the Stylesheet:

```
[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[StyleSheet alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

That's it ... in the Stylesheet, change the `UIFont` and `RGBCOLOR(0, 0, 0)` to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: 
http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/552d453dea748645

Basically you need to set a TTStyleSheet and perform all you customizations there.