# Three20 TTLauncherItem style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

How can I set the text color to black for a `TTLauncherItem` from the Three20 library? I have seen that the style property is `NSString`.

I'm trying to assign something like this:

```
TTTextStyle *aux = [TTTextStyle styleWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] color:RGBCOLOR(80, 80, 80) minimumFontSize:12 shadowColor:nil shadowOffset:CGSizeZero next:nil];
```

I have seen that there are some examples with subclassing a style and overriding it for a button but isn't there any easier solution like just assigning a style/color that I want to a `TTLauncherItem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following tutorial on implementing `TTStyleSheet` properly:

[Three20 Stylesheets iPhone Tutorial](http://mattvague.com/three20-stylesheets-tutorial)

Also see the following SO answer as well:

[How to change the color of the title in TTLauncherItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770467/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-title-in-ttlauncheritem)